# How authentication is done between two nodes in tcp/ip or udp client server socket

Tags: c, socket, tcp-ip

I have a client socket program and server socket  program in C TCP/IP .  I execute the server program first on a port say 5000 and then executes client program on the same port and then server respond to it via listen and accept system call.  But ,i want to know how the authentication is odne between client and server as i am not using any username or password of remote node.

Comment: it is not done.

Answer (score 1):

By default there is no authentication, so long as the client uses the apropriate socket number the server will accept the connection.

look as SSL and SASL for some examples of authentication.